# Is there a way to define SASS variables in a" [data='value'] {}", or only regular CSS variables?

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vite

I want to export "$var" like variables defined as "--var" variables from a Scss file to be used in other files with some scss functions such as "darken()", but it says its not a color.

I'm coding a Vue/Vite website and implementing a theme-change button, that will write data at the HTML tag, and use it to define the theme.

```
<html lang="en" data-theme="dark"> ... </html>
```

The base.scss looks like this:

```
[data-theme="dark"] {
  --primary: #c6c7df;
  --secondary: #c95d63;
  --text-light: #e2ebf5;
}

[data-theme="light"] {
  --primary: #26298d;
  --secondary: #c95d63;
  --text-light: #2c3e50;
}

$primary: var(--primary);
$secondary: var(--secondary);
$text-light: var(--text-light);
```

I can use the "$var"-like variable at the end of the file, but when I use it inside a "darken($primary, 10%)" function, it gives the following error:

```
Error: $color: var(--primary) is not a color.
```

I know it's because I defined it as a CSS variable but if I define the variable inside the "[theme] {}" thing, it doesn't get innitialized and throws the error "Undefined variable"

I know it's a niche question, and I could use something like [this](https://medium.com/beyn-technology/using-css-variables-in-scss-functions-9521be4de4e3), but I wish I could just export it as a scss variable.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Of course we cannot make a CSS variable lighten or darken. Think about, What will happen to the Name of CSS variable in the output?
So we have to define all CSS variables and assign desired colors, Before using them.

### Solution

For this purpose, you can automatically create the list of CSS variables by `@each` and create a manual function by `@function` for easy use. This way gives us a standard css output and the best experience in Sass coding.

```
// Theme defines area:
$theme-colors:(
    "primary": #940fe0,
    "secondary": #e49f38,
    "warning": #ffe600,
    "info": #165ad6
);
$darken-percent: 20%;
$lighten-percent: 20%;

// Functions area:
:root {
    @each $name, $color in $theme-colors {
        $lighten: lighten($color, $lighten-percent);
        $darken: darken($color, $darken-percent);
        --color-#{$name}: #{$color};
        --color-#{$name}-light: #{$lighten};
        --color-#{$name}-dark: #{$darken};
    }
}
@function cl($name, $color-tone) {
    @if not map-get($theme-colors, $name+''){
        @error "`#{$name}` is not defined in Colors Theme";
    }
    @if $color-tone == d {
        @return var(--color-#{$name}-dark);
    }
    @if $color-tone == l {
        @return var(--color-#{$name}-light);
    }
    @else{
        @return var(--color-#{$name});
    }
}
// Our custom function usage: 
// Use 'b' to return Base color. Ex: cl(primary,b)
// Use 'l' to return Lighten color. Ex: cl(primary,l)
// Use 'd' to return Darken color. Ex: cl(primary,d)

.test {
    color: cl(primary,b);
    color: cl(warning,l);
}
```

Compiled css result:

```
:root {
  --color-primary: #940fe0;
  --color-primary-light: #bf61f4;
  --color-primary-dark: #550980;
  --color-secondary: #e49f38;
  --color-secondary-light: #f0ca92;
  --color-secondary-dark: #a06916;
  --color-warning: #ffe600;
  --color-warning-light: #fff066;
  --color-warning-dark: #998a00;
  --color-info: #165ad6;
  --color-info-light: #6395ef;
  --color-info-dark: #0c337a;
}

.test {
  color: var(--color-primary);
  color: var(--color-warning-light);
```